# preventing users from submitting data from form to mysql twice

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where a user submits data from various text fields on my webpage to mysql database. Is there any code I can use were it will not let them submit/update the data again? e.g it will redirect them to a page saying sorry wwe have already received your data.

I have a unique number for each user if this helps.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: You just query the db for the values that you think can be duplicate (using POST values), and if that query returns one or more rows, you don't run insert query, but display some message instead. No need to re-direct anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use tokens, it will avoid double submits and CSRFs.

Simply add tokens to an array, $_session most likely, and pop them when used.

Also, disable the submit button with JS after a submit.

You can also set a var in the session user that says he already performed an action, exampled uploaded his picture. Unset it if there is an error in your upload script for instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the post, query the database for the unique user number.  If you get back a non-empty result, then display the error.  Otherwise, save the data to the database.

The biggest thing you need to determine is what your unique identifier will be.  It sounds as though you already have one (you mentioned unique user number?)  Your unique identifier could be an email address, or even the full set of submitted data.

There are other ways to emulate this, such as setting a cookie on the user's machine, or disabling the submit button, but, none of these are completely under your control.  The user could easily get past them if they tried.  Therefore, determining a unique identifier and validating server side is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer hugely depends on the *reason* for which user might send the data twice.

- in case of an **accident**, there is one technique, and all other won't help you even a bit.
- in case of **intentional** duplication the technique is **completely different** and again there is no general solution - everything depends on the certain scenario.

If you care to explain your certain case, you will get a proper solution.

For the most silly case of pressing "Reload" on a page with post results, you have to redirect browser using `Location:` HTTP header, e.g.

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
```

Comment: at the minute if the user submits the form data they can login and submit it again. I want it to display 'sorry you have already selected your data' once they login. Code would be helpful.

Comment: for the "code that would be helpful" you may apply to whatever freelance job site. Here is a humble Q/A site, not a free codes site.